# Почему сдвигается каретка python-скрипта в консоли?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

Суть: есть скрипт который в цикле, печатает посредством такой функции (вызывается каждую итерацию цикла)

```
"""
total - Общая длина списка
progress - Текущий индекс
comment - аннтоация
"""
current_ = current + 1
progress = current_/total
block = round(bar_length * progress)
draw = "#" * block + "-" * (bar_length - block)
percents = round(progress * 100, 0)
text = "\r{comment}, итерация {count_iter}, документов удалено {delete_docs}, ошибок удаления {error_docs}:" \
       " [{draw}] {percents}%".format(comment=comment, count_iter=count_iter, draw=draw,
                                      percents=percents, delete_docs=delete_docs, error_docs=error_docs)
sys.stdout.write(text)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

В пайчарме работает норм - каретка каждую итерацию цикла возвращается в начало строки[image: Работа скрипта в пай-чарме]
Прим этом, если запустить скрипт из винды, то каретка каждую итеграцию перескакивает на новую строку, в чем может быть проблема?[image: Работа скрипта при запуске из винды]

Comment: Очевидно, в одну строку по ширине не влезает, вот и перескакивает. И в pycharm будет перескакивать, если вы окно сузите